# Buttons color in tableview cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm trying to build quiz app and the questions displayed in a table view 
each cell have four buttons ( the answers ).

the problem is when I click on one of the buttons, it's being selected in some other cell also.

Comment: How have you created the buttons? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because UITableViewCells are being reused you have to 'reset' cell state every time you dequeue it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

One alternative is to override the prepareForReuse method in your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // Reset the state of cell's properties, e.g. selected state background color
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it's resetting the entire table each time i select something

Comment: You have to implement this method in your custom UITableViewCell class and only reset state of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the right `indexPath.row` value when you are selecting in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`